# lsp mode for dart support on spacemacs

Tags: emacs, dart, flutter, spacemacs

I want to setup dart support on [spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs), android studio takes up too much resource and I already have spacemacs keybindings on muscle memory.
I have had a look at [Averrins's implementation](https://github.com/averrin/dart-layer) which is unfortunately deprecated and there is a proposal that I use `lsp` mode for dart.
tried following through [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/11161) but cannot customize it for dart-mode.
How can I use lsp mode for dart support on spacemacs (I am on the **develop** branch - **emacs 26.1**)

Comment: you can use `vs-code`. vs-code also takes fewer resources. look at the flutter documents and don't waste your time by different tools because still flutter is under developing and it's possible to you have many mistakes.

Comment: The biggest issue is that I am used to emacs keybindings I cannot seem to be productive on other editors

Comment: I'm happy using the emacs keybindings on VSCode, and find the whole VSCode environment much more friendly, since I had not previously used IntelliJ products.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to explore [lsp-dart](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-dart),

> Emacs Dart IDE using [lsp-mode](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode)
> to connect to [Dart Analysis
> Server](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/tree/master/pkg/analysis_server).

Check the example on how you can setup `lsp-dart`:

> ````
> "http://melpa.org/packages/") t) (package-initialize)
>
> (setq package-selected-packages    '(dart-mode lsp-mode lsp-dart
> lsp-treemacs flycheck company
>     ;; Optional packages
>     lsp-ui company hover))
>
> (when (cl-find-if-not #'package-installed-p package-selected-packages)
> (package-refresh-contents)   (mapc #'package-install
> package-selected-packages))
>
> (add-hook 'dart-mode-hook 'lsp)
>
> (setq gc-cons-threshold (* 100 1024 1024)
>       read-process-output-max (* 1024 1024)) ```
> ````